# gcc -m32 cannot find libraries

Tags: 12.04, gcc

Both 32 and 64 bit compiles worked and then I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04.  Now -m64 works but -m32 can't find libraries.

I've tried reinstalling libraries, and gcc-multilib but no joy.  Anyone spot something I've missed?

David

```
gcc -m32 -Wall -W -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 -lusb-1.0
-lX11 LMSS.c -o LMSS32
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

locate libusb-1.0
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8.tar.bz2
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/AUTHORS
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/COPYING
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/ChangeLog
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/INSTALL
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/Makefile
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/Makefile.am
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/Makefile.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/NEWS
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/PORTING
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/README
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/THANKS
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/TODO
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/aclocal.m4
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/compile
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/config.guess
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/config.h
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/config.h.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/config.log
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/config.status
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/config.sub
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/configure
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/configure.ac
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/depcomp
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/doc
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/install-sh
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libtool
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb-1.0.pc
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb-1.0.pc.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/ltmain.sh
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/missing
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/stamp-h1
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/doc/Makefile
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/doc/Makefile.am
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/doc/Makefile.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/doc/doxygen.cfg
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/doc/doxygen.cfg.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/.deps
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/Makefile
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/Makefile.am
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/Makefile.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/dpfp.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/dpfp_threaded.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/lsusb.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/.deps/dpfp.Po
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/.deps/dpfp_threaded-dpfp_threaded.Po
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/examples/.deps/lsusb.Po
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/Makefile
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/Makefile.am
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/Makefile.in
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/core.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/descriptor.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/io.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb-1.0.la
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb.h
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-core.lo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-core.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-descriptor.lo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-descriptor.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-io.lo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-io.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-linux_usbfs.lo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-linux_usbfs.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-sync.lo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusb_1_0_la-sync.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/libusbi.h
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/os
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/sync.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps/libusb_1_0_la-core.Plo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps/libusb_1_0_la-darwin_usb.Plo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps/libusb_1_0_la-descriptor.Plo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps/libusb_1_0_la-io.Plo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps/libusb_1_0_la-linux_usbfs.Plo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.deps/libusb_1_0_la-sync.Plo
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb-1.0.a
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb-1.0.la
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb-1.0.lai
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb-1.0.so
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb-1.0.so.0
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb-1.0.so.0.0.0
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb_1_0_la-core.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb_1_0_la-descriptor.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb_1_0_la-io.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb_1_0_la-linux_usbfs.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/.libs/libusb_1_0_la-sync.o
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/os/darwin_usb.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/os/darwin_usb.h
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/os/linux_usbfs.c
/home/david/Downloads/libusb-1.0.8/libusb/os/linux_usbfs.h
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
/usr/include/libusb-1.0
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0
/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/README
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/PORTING
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/README
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/annotated.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/bc_s.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/caveats.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/classes.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/closed.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/contexts.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/doxygen.css
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/doxygen.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/dynsections.js
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/files.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/functions.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/functions_vars.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__asyncio.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__desc.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__dev.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__lib.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__misc.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__poll.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/group__syncio.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/index.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/io.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/libusb_8h_source.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/modules.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/mtasync.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/nav_f.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/nav_h.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/open.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/packetoverflow.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/pages.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__config__descriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__control__setup.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__device__descriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__endpoint__descriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__interface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__interface__descriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__iso__packet__descriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__pollfd.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/structlibusb__transfer.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/tab_a.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/tab_b.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/tab_h.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/tab_s.png
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/tabs.css
/usr/share/doc/libusb-1.0-0-dev/html/version_8h_source.html
/usr/share/doc-base/libusb-1.0-0-dev
/var/cache/apt/archives/libusb-1.0-0-dev_2%3a1.0.9~rc3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libusb-1.0-0_2%3a1.0.9~rc3-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/doc-base/documents/libusb-1.0-0-dev
/var/lib/doc-base/omf/libusb-1.0-0-dev
/var/lib/doc-base/omf/libusb-1.0-0-dev/libusb-1.0-0-dev-C.omf
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0-dev.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libusb-1.0-0:amd64.shlibs
```

Comment: First, you are listing a *file* after the the -L flag, instead of a directory. Secondly, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` constains *64-bit* libraries, not 32 bit. Are you trying to cross-compile from 64 bit system to 32 bits?

Comment: I corrected the -L flag and then got more incompatible libs so I am obviously missing the 32 bit libs.  Any pointers as to where they will be?  I'm really annoyed I upgraded as I had everything working before.  David

Comment: 11.10 gcc LMSS.c -m64 -Wall -W -lusb-1.0 -lx11 -o LMSS64 gcc and LMSS.c -m32 -Wall -W -lusb-1.0 -lx11 -o LMSS32 worked 12.04 gcc LMSS.c -m64 -Wall -W -lusb-1.0 -lx11 -o LMSS64 works and I just need to sort 32bit compile for 32 bit target. David

Answer (score 3):

You *could* install the 32-bit packages for these libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libusb-dev:i386 libX11-dev:i386
```

Note, however, that this will remove the 64-bit versions. Probably it's better to use a chroot (e.g. with cowbuilder or pbuilder) or Qemu image for this kind of thing. E.g. create the file `~/.pbuilderrc-precise-i386`:

```sh
# Set this to the distribution you want to build for
DISTRIBUTION=precise
# The architecture you want to build for
ARCHITECTURE=i386
# The directory in which to store the chroot base image
BASEPATH=/var/cache/pbuilder/base-precise-i386.cow
# The repositories to be enabled in the /etc/apt/sources.list
COMPONENTS="main universe"
# If you want to speed things up with ccache, enable these options
export CCACHE_DIR="/var/cache/pbuilder/ccache"
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:${PATH}"
# List here all packages you need to build your software
# (e.g. build-essential, libusb-dev, libX11-dev, etc.)
EXTRAPACKAGES=ccache
# List here all directories from you system that should be visible inside the chroot
BINDMOUNTS="${CCACHE_DIR} ${HOME}/projects"
```

Then install *cowbuilder* and create the base image as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cowbuilder
$ sudo cowbuilder --create --configfile ~/.pbuilderrc-precise-i386
```

Lastly, enter the chroot and finish configuring it (copy over configuration files:

```
$ sudo cowbuilder --login --save-after-exec --configfile ~/.pbuilderrc-precise-i386
```

You can exit the chroot using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or using `exit`. Now you have set up your base-image. In the future, don't use the `--save-after-exec` flag any more when entering the chroot. This ensures that all the modifications will be discarded after you leave the chroot, ensuring a clean build environment for future builds.

Now you should be able to enter the chroot and build your software:

```
$ sudo cowbuilder --login --configfile ~/.pbuilderrc-precise-i386
% cd $HOME/projects/foo
% # build project foo
```

Note, however, that the files created in this way will be owned by `root`. Hence, out-of-source builds are a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play with that.  I think ia32-libs is broken and so I installed 32 bit libs for libusb and x11.  I had to reinstall gcc but it is up and running - enough for my current need.  I'll look at chroot approach and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 2):

Something is broken with multiarch, I could no longer compile 32-bit apps on 64-bit machine with fresh 12.04.1 and its multiarch (everything installed) using -m32 switch. In my case I needed libQtCore and any attempt to install libqt4-dev:i386 tried to unsinstall libqt4-dev! 
After fiddling around I figured out some symbolic links were missing in "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu" then compile proceeded.